# Fedora GNOME User Configuration

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, user-accounts

I have some capturing tools and they cannot be ran without root user logged in the GUI, so I did the following actions in order.
1. I deleted the /root folder and linked it to my /home directory.
2. Changed the userid the normal user to 0.
3. Deleted the user and added it back with UID 1000.

Now the system has some problems:
1. The Icon on the GUI login page has disappeared, only a "Not listed" button is available.
2. All user configurations, including Firefox, will be overwritten upon login.
3. IBus, Tor daemons cannot be started properly.
4. "User" panel in GNOME crashed.

I'm asking for a recover of my nornal user so that all the GUI logins appears normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch. That's a pretty dangerous approach.

You should be able to fix it, though, with:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/$USERNAME
$ sudo restorecon -R -v /home/$USERNAME
$ sudo mkdir /root
$ sudo restorecon -R -v /root
$ sudo dnf reinstall rootfiles
```

That:

1. Fixes ownership of your home directory
2. Fixes SELinux on those files
3. Recreates root's home directory
4. Fixes SELinux on those files
5. Puts back the default config files for the root user.